# ansible variables shared with multiple groups if inventory is only localhost

Tags: ansible, kubernetes, ansible-inventory

I use ansible to send jobs / configurations to my k8s cluster via the kubectl command on my local machine. I have my inventory file setup so that each cluster is it's own group and each cluster is basically a connection to localhost .

```
# Inventory File
#
[east.k.example.com]
localhost              ansible_connection=local

[east2.k.example.com]
localhost              ansible_connection=local
```

Then in my group_vars directory I have a different file with the name of my group from my inventory file that holds all the different variables for each cluster.

I limit my runs to target only one cluster with the limit option:
`ansible-playbook -vv create.yaml -l east2.k.example.com --tags ingress-generate-only`

The problem is that when I attempt to use variables in my templates I get variables from the other groups. I'm thinking because each group includes localhost.

Is there a better way to solve this issue?  Can I set a flag so that groups only include the variables from the group_var files?

thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Refactor your inventory to use distinct names:

```
# Inventory File
#
[east.k.example.com]
east ansible_connection=local

[east2.k.example.com]
east2 ansible_connection=local
```

This way Ansible will treat them as different hosts, thus not merging variables from different groups.

Comment: OMG Thank you so much!!! You have no idea how hard I've been trying to solve this issue.

Comment: Thank for this. I spent a lot of time to figure out if it was a bug or what

Comment: What happens if I run a play without limiting (`--limit`) to one of these 'locals'? I'm very scared that if I'm running on 'east' Ansible would run like it were 'east2'.

Answer (score 0):

In YAML syntax

```yaml
all:
  children:
    east.k.example.com:
      hosts:
        east:
          ansible_connection: local
    east2.k.example.com:
      hosts:
        east2:
          ansible_connection: local
```